# Integration test sqlite in memory database give error in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, integration-testing, system.data.sqlite

I setup integration testing in my .NET Core application but in line number 53 (i.e `appContext.Database.EnsureCreated()`) I get an error:

> $exception {"SQLite Error 1: 'near "''": syntax error'."}
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong?

```
using Asp.Versioning;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using World.Persistence.DBContext;


namespace World.Integration.Tests
{
    public abstract class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(DbContextOptions<WorldDBContext>));

                services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor!);

                var dbConnectionDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(DbConnection));

                _ = services.Remove(dbConnectionDescriptor!);

                // Create open SqliteConnection so EF won't automatically close it.
                services.AddSingleton<DbConnection>(container =>
                {
                    var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
                    connection.Open();

                    return connection;
                });

                services.AddDbContext<WorldDBContext>((container, options) =>
                {
                    var connection = container.GetRequiredService<DbConnection>();
                    options.UseSqlite(connection);
                });

                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                using var scope = sp.CreateScope();
                using var appContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<WorldDBContext>();

                try
                {
                    appContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            });

            builder.UseEnvironment("Development");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the error is occuring on `EnsureCreated` it is likely coming from your schema.  You need to post the relevant code.

Comment: @possum you can take a look in [repo](https://github.com/Aksh-kumar/World.CleanArchitecture.git)  while running countryIntegrationtest it gives me this error **Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 1: 'near "''": syntax error**

Comment: No.  Post the code here so that it is archived and searchable for others.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue with your codes,when `EnsureCreated()` method is called,it would create db and tables accroding the configuration in your case,and the error was caused by invalid Sql in your `.HasDefaultValueSql()` method in `WorldDBContext`.

Comment: It is coming directly from database, I scaffold it to create DBContext from SQL server.

Comment: You could try remove it and test again

Comment: I tried to remove it it is working but via api post call insertion into database in not happening, can you tell me If I can use any other in memory sql database approach so that I don't have to modify DBContext since I am getting this from reverse engineering.